# `smartindent` indents four tabs?

Tags: indentation

I'm just looking for a very basic indentation scheme. In `.vimrc` I have `:set tabstop=2`. Adding `:set smartindent` has the effect of indenting the code by four tabs, very strange? A single tab the size of four spaces would be fine (despite my preferred tabstop), but four tabs? What is the issue here? `:set cindent` has the same effect.

edit: vim 7.4 on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set tabstop=2` means tabs are displayed as at most 2 characters, it does not control the amount of indent.  You have `shiftwidth=8` which controls the amount of indent.    When vim indents (assuming `noexpandtab`), it tries to use tabs first, hence you get 4 tabs of 2 apparent spaces each for a total of 4*2=8 spaces equivalent indent.  The solution is to set `shiftwidth` appropriately

Comment: Note that setting `'shiftwidth'` to zero means that the value for `'tabstop'` will also be used for shiftwidth.